# How to use custom text data format for sklearn's CountVectorizer()?

Tags: text, scikit-learn

There is a nice [introduction on how to use sklearn for text analytics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

But in the upper tutorial they use sklearn's dataset with their 'bunch' object which is not specified in detail, therefore I struggle to put my data in the desired form to use sklearn methods on it.
I'd like to use the [CountVectorizer()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) on my text data for further processing, but calling the CountVectorizer.fit_transform(my_string_array) always throws some error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

I've tried so far initializing the following numpy array types and loaded my string into them but none of them worked:

1. np.chararray(shape)
2. np.empty(shape, dtype = str/obj)

Answer (score 0):

A simplified example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

docs = ['This is the first document', 'This is the second document']
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(docs)
```

`docs` should be a collection of strings, i.e. a list, numpy array, etc.

If the text is already tokenized then you need to tell `CountVectorizer` that it doesn't need to split the string:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

docs = [['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'document'], 
        ['This', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document']]
count_vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda text: text)
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(docs)
```

Comment: the problem is that my data an array of arrays of strings, ie. [['string1', 'string2', ....], ['string1', 'string2', ....], .... ]

Comment: @ben0it8, Ok, why is your data 2D instead of 1D (collection of docs)? Have you already tokenized the documents?

Comment: Yes, each element in my array corresponds to one document's strings.

Comment: @ben0it8 why is it then 2D instead of 1D? Is it already tokenized? Please see my edits or add an example of how your data looks like if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The CountVectorizer requires a Sequence or a list of strings to process as [mentioned here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

> input : string {‘filename’, ‘file’, ‘content’}
>
> If ‘filename’, the sequence passed as an argument to fit is expected to be a list of filenames that need reading to fetch the raw content to analyze.
>
> If ‘file’, the sequence items must have a ‘read’ method (file-like object) that is called to fetch the bytes in memory.
>
> Otherwise the input is expected to be the **sequence strings** or bytes items are expected to be analyzed directly.

You are providing `[['string1', 'string2', ....], ['string1', 'string2', ....]`. The outer one is an array, so that requirement is complete.

Then the CountVectorizer() iterates the elements of the list you provided.

It expects: `object of type string`, and calls `lower()` (to make the lowercase strings) on that.
It gets: `['string1', 'string2', ....]` which is a list and obviously **doesn't have lower() method**. Hence the error.

**Solution**:
In my opinion it will not change the results if instead of list of list of strings, only a single list is used which is passed to CountVectorizer().

Mke the inner list of strings (per document list you are using) a single string by doing:

`data = [" ".join(x) for x in data]`

where `data` is your string data with list of list of strings.

Assuming your data is:

```
data = [['yo', 'dude'],['how','are', 'you']]
data = [" ".join(x) for x in data]
```

Output:

```
['yo dude', 'how are you']
```

This can be now passed on to CountVectorizer with no errors.